# Magento Product page shows QUANTITY as 0

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quantity

My website shows quaintity as 0, but when I add product to cart its one, Can I change it so that it shows quantity 1

Here is sample:

http://milkywaytshirts.com/bestsellers/super-dad-superhero-t-shirt.html

Answer (score 2):

Edit the product, go to the inventory tab and set the value 1 (or check the "use config" checkbox) for the "Minimum qty allowed in cart."

Answer (score 1):

This input field value is coming from `getProductDefaultQty` function of block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.

According  this function This field value depends `on getMinimalQty() and getPreconfiguredValues()->getQty()` and `set between highest value of this two functions`.

```
 $qty = $this->getMinimalQty($product);
        $config = $product->getPreconfiguredValues();
        $configQty = $config->getQty();
        if ($configQty > $qty) {
            $qty = $configQty;
        }
```

`Minimal qty` field in `managed by min_sale_qty(Minimum qty allowed in cart.) field  of Products Inventory` .It can this from `admin>Product Inventory field`

and `getPreconfiguredValues()->getQty()` function  `only work for group products because for group  have multiple product`.

**It mean this input field depends on mini_sale_qty field**

Answer (score 0):

When you add the product to your cart if it is 0 it automatically makes it 1. If you set it to 3, 10, or whatever quantity it will add that quantity instead. Otherwise what is the point of adding 0 of a product to the cart?

Comment: I think its confusing for customers, Quantity is shown as 0,is still adds quantity 1

Comment: This worked for me http://magentolore.quora.com/Set-default-product-quantity-to-one-in-Magento-i-e-not-default-zero

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

> Login in magento admin
>
> Go to System -> Config -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product stock options

- Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart Select customer group like (ALL GROUPS) and add your qty value.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following to display 1 in the Qty input fields on the frontend:

1. In admin menu go to **System -> Configuration**
2. Then on right side go to **Catalog -> Inventory**
3. Then left side find **Product Stock Options** accordion tab
4. Then find **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** option
5. Click on the **Add Minimum Qty** button
6. Choose *Customer Group*: **ALL GROUPS** (if you want all users)
7. Enter **1** for *Minimum Qty*
8. Click the **Save Config** button

Now it will display a default number of 1 for all Qty input boxes.